# Segmentation fault in program but GDB doesn't show line number

Tags: c, gdb, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a List ADT in C. I am new to C and am trying to translate a code from Java into C. However, when I am testing the List ADT, I keep getting a segmentation fault.

When I debug the program in GDB, I get the following error:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x0000000000400be8 in getIndex ()

And then when I type in the command "where," I get the following message:

> #0  0x0000000000400be8 in getIndex ()
>
> #1  0x0000000000400806 in main ()

The code below is the method getIndex() that the error occurs in:

```
int getIndex(List L) {
   int returnIndex = 0;
   if (offEnd(L)) return -1;
   else {
      NodeRef currIndex = L->curr;
      while (currIndex != L->front) {
         ++returnIndex;
         currIndex = currIndex->prev;
      }
   }
   return returnIndex;
}
```

For reference, the offEnd() method and the struct for the NodeRef are:

```
int offEnd(List L) {
   if (L == NULL) {
      printf("List Error: Calling offEnd() on NULL List\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   return (L->length == 0);
}
```

---

```
typedef struct Node {
   int data;
   struct Node* next;
   struct Node* prev;
} Node;

typedef Node* NodeRef;

typedef struct ListObj {
   NodeRef front;
   NodeRef back;
   NodeRef curr;
   int length;
} ListObj;

NodeRef newNode(int node_data) {
   NodeRef N = malloc(sizeof(Node));
   N->data = node_data;
   N->next = NULL;
   N->prev = NULL;
   return (N);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to C and struggling. Thank you.

Comment: On which operating system and with which compiler (and which version) are you coding?

Comment: Is `List` the same as `ListObj`? Show more code, in particular the definition (e.g. `typedef`) of `List` ...

Comment: -1 because you don't explain what is `List` ....

Comment: `while (currIndex != L->front) {` : `currIndex` is `NULL`?

Comment: This was an incredibly helpful question since I had this problem on FreeBSD and found this via Google.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, you should compile with all warnings and debug info

```
 gcc -Wall -g yoursource.c -o yourbinary
```

<sup>Of course, improve the code till you get no warnings at all.</sup>

Perhaps `getIndex` is called with a `NULL` argument. You might add

```
#include <assert.h>
```

near the start of `yoursource.c` file and code:

```
int getIndex(List L) {
  int returnIndex = 0;
  assert (L != NULL);
  if (offEnd(L)) return -1;
  else {
    NodeRef currIndex = L->curr;
    while (currIndex != L->front) {
       ++returnIndex;
       currIndex = currIndex->prev;
    }
 }
 return returnIndex;
}
```

Read about [assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) and [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html).

BTW, my opinion is that pointers are so important in C that you always need to explicit them. So have a `typedef struct listnode_st ListNode;` and declare `ListNode* L` (or perhaps `ListObj* l`, I don't know what `List` is) instead of `List L`. I also prefer uppercase for macros, so would suggest declaring `int getindex(ListNode*l)` with a lowercase `l` and adapt the body of that function accordingly.

At last, your `newNode` is wrong: `malloc` can fail and you always should handle such a failure. So start it with

```
NodeRef newNode(int node_data) {
  NodeRef N = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if (N == NULL) { perror("malloc Node"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Beware of [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak); read more about [C dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), [pointer aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_alias), [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29); read carefully [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html); consider (at least on Linux) using a memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).